# Shared ViewModel in MVI

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm, android-mvp

How to use shared viewmodel in MVI architecture? Is it actually used to communicate between fragments, or do we use an interface, or a broadcast receiver? That part is not clear to me, and I can't find it anywhere. What is best practice? Thanks all

Comment: If I understand your concern correctly, you want to have a single ViewModel that is used in multiple activities/fragments. If that is the case, you may take a look at Dependency Injection which will allow you to create a ViewModel as a singleton and use in multiple fragments/activities. Inside viewModel, you can save a state of your app and in activities/fragments, you can observe changes of your VM and act according to those changes

Answer (score 0):

You should use MVVM architecture, Take a reference from below code it will help you.

```
//Fragment A
class FragmentA:Fragment {
private lateinit var viewModel:LoginViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = 
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
}
}

//Fragment B
class FragmentB:Fragment {
private lateinit var viewModel:LoginViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = 
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
}
}

//This is share viewModel class
class LoginViewModel: ViewModel{

}
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. But what if I want to have a viewModel in the scope of the Fragment and a viewModel in the scope of the Activity? Is it good to place those two things within the Fragment? Because I don't want to write some functions in SharedViewModel that concern only one Fragment, there is no need to see them in other Fragments